# How to generate contents via array {} into merged cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to fill contents using array {} (cell A1) into a range of cells (C1,D1 & C2) in Google Sheets containing merged cells like shown in picture. Wonder if there is a smart way like "span=2" in html!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can you try:*

```js
=vstack({"A","B"},{"C"})
```

[image]